# Part Of Mesh Becomes Inverted After Parenting To Armature

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, motion-capture

I am attempting to use Kinect V2 for motion capture in blender. After playing around with locations and rotations of bones I finally found out what was causing the unintended contortions in my mesh, but one problem still remains. The character's hip region is deformed but the rest of the character is fine, so I'm not sure what is causing this. Pictures are below:

[image]

Here is the link to the blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzB2Ay4lZC0ocnM5TFIyWm84cUU/view?usp=sharing .

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is why does this occur and how can I fix it.

Comment: I think You must apply the trasformations of the character. The origin point is so far from the armature too. Try to make the armature and the character the same size and align both.